# Problem presenting a UIActionSheet from a double tap in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

I am presenting a UIActionSheet when a user double taps my cell:

Tap Recognition in Cell Init:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                            initWithTarget:self 
                                             action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];

        [doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
        [doubleTap release];
```

Tell the delegate to handle the tap:

```
- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"double oo");
    [delegate handleDoubleTapp];
}
```

Now the delegate which is my UITableViewController will present the UIActionSheet:

```
-(void)handleDoubleTapp{

        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                       initWithTitle:nil
                                       delegate:self
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                       destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                       otherButtonTitles:@"Reply", @"Retweet", @"Direct Message", nil] autorelease];    
        [actionSheet showInView:self.parentViewController.tabBarController.view];

    }   
}
```

My UITableViewController implements the UIActionSheet delegate methods properly.

Problems:

1. Not all areas of the actionsheet are responsive
2. Clicking on a button presents a modal view, but the actionsheet does not get dismissed
3. When buttons are able to be clicked, they don't highlight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a thought: did you try unregistering the UIGestureRecognizer once the UIActionSheet is about to become visible and re-registering it when the action sheet is dismissed? Maybe the recognizer is interfering with the touches.

Comment: How can I unregister the recognizer?

Comment: I added: [recognizer removeTarget:nil action:NULL]; in handleDoubleTap. This fixed the problem, however after I double click on a cell once, I can't double click on it again. Where is the right place to unregister? Where is the right place to register?

Comment: Instead of removing, I just set the enabled state to false. Re-enabled it in the delegate after the action sheet displayed. Great tip.

Comment: Perfect - I'm glad I was able to point you in the right direction. Good find regarding enabled / disabled state instead of adding / removing!